# Changing my backbone.js router

Tags: backbone.js

I have a web application with require.js, backbone.js and jquery.
The brief structure of the app is as follows:

- There are 2 sections on the screen (toolbar and main content below).
- There are multiple components (address management, event management), each triggered by a hash fragment change and require a
  page transition.
- There is one backbone.js router. It's the heart of the application. The router is activated with a new hash fragment (manually entered,
  back button, menu item selection).

Up until now, in the router, I made the page transition, I DIRECTLY called the controller ("view" in backbone) of the selected component.

So there's a CENTRAL handling of controller calling.

But this has to change now to a DISTRIBUTED handling. I now need to respond to a new hash fragment from two different places: From the toolbar component and from router.
So my idea is to exchange the direct controller calling mechanism with pub sub. Now MULTIPLE components could register for a special action and the router just "fires the event".

I searched around and found Chaplin (https://github.com/moviepilot/chaplin), a backbone.js example application.

The developers of Chaplin seem to have a similiar thing called "ApplicationView" (https://github.com/moviepilot/chaplin#toc-router-and-route):

> "Between the router and the controllers, there’s the ApplicationView as
>   a dispatcher."

Is there anyone who has already this kind of architecture and can tell me his experience with this or has anybody solved this in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a similar, though maybe less complex, architecture in [this project](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/gapvis). I give a pretty good explanation in [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002828/large-backbone-js-web-app-organization/8003241#8003241). The quick overview:

- I manage app-wide events that change the application state using a singleton `State` model that works similarly to Chaplin's pub/sub architecture. This is just a basic Backbone model, with some added methods to deal with serializing and deserializing attributes as strings, so they can be set in the URL.
- Application components that change the application state in response to user interaction or other input do so by setting properties on `app.state`.
- Components that need to update when the application state changes do so by binding to `change` events on `app.state` (it looks like this is exactly the way Chaplin's `mediator` works, though they renamed the methods to fit the pub/sub paradigm).
- I treat my routers like specialized views that update the address bar and respond to user input in that area. Changing the address (manually or by clicking on a link) causes the router to `set()` the necessary changes on the `app.state` model, and everything else updates accordingly.

I hope that's helpful - I think it's a little simpler than the Chaplin approach.